# json_decode returning random numbers

Tags: php

I'm trying to print the distance in km between two ZIP codes, using this [Zip Code API](https://www.zipcodeapi.com/API#distance).

My code:

```
$settings = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://www.zipcodeapi.com/rest/rDJ7VmDHWP7NVwCXRbznkauB5DddKBQbeAjaWXSSM0FIxiFoueMPohquUDIFfzQt/distance.json/45410/45412/km'), true);
print_r($settings['distance']);
```

When I visit the [actual link](https://www.zipcodeapi.com/rest/rDJ7VmDHWP7NVwCXRbznkauB5DddKBQbeAjaWXSSM0FIxiFoueMPohquUDIFfzQt/distance.json/45410/45412/km), it returns the expected result of 3.635 km. However, the code actually prints out seemingly random numbers, such as 17.04, 90.79, and 46.33 (my last 3 attempts).

I am running this on Cloud9, I have tried isolating it on a new page.

Am I I using `json_decode` wrong or does this seem like an issue with the API?

Comment: What does your data look like?

Comment: When I run that, I see `3.635`.

Comment: I have run it on a new page in Cloud9, because I do not have a web server set up to execute the PHP code. [Here is the preview link](https://bandfinder-watercolour.c9users.io/ziptest.php)

Comment: I ran it and got the expected result, so then changed the zip codes to ones I know, and the results were way off. This API is not accurate for determining distance between two zips. It's probably not your code, it's the API causing problems.

Comment: @JakeGould, I added a preview link when the code is isolated in my above comment, which only contains the code in my question plus `<br><b>test</b>`. Visiting the actual site gives you correct info, but I just discovered that getting requests from the API without registering on their site will generate random numbers. Quite silly, but once I registered it worked with my new key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the API I was using requires you to register an API key in order to use it properly, or else it will generate random values. I registered and it only allows up to 50 requests per hour with the free key, but it worked once I used the key from registering.

For those that are looking for an API with a higher request/day limit, [Google's API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/start) works well also.